# Passing request object from asp.net mvc controller to backend services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a request object from a controller to a back end service/class which would perform some operations based on the request cookie and return the appropriate result. Is it a good design pattern to pass a request object around or are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: You can pass only whatever is needed for your backend services.

Comment: yes, request object is more controller specific, so avoid to pass it to back end classes. bind the needed properties to a user defined class object named requestDAO and pass it to service classes and do the needfull

Comment: Thanks a lot!! will certainly follow that.